# How to use a Pivot Function to show data for a yr's span

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, pivot, pivot-table

I have report that was coded I was told some time ago, and it shows data for a 'Ratings' and 'Result' column across the span of a year.

Currently the script is using Case statements to acheive this, however I believe this is what the Pivot Function is for and could save some lines of code. Can anyone assist me in changing the logic to use a pivot function?Current Logic:

```
    Select
EmployeeID, 
Employee, 
--Datetype, 
EmpGroupID, 
PA, 
EmpLevel, 
ObjectiveName as Objective, 
Objectiveid AS Objectiveid,
Weighting,
ReportingYear,

max(Case When r.DateType = 'M' 
          and Month(r.StartDate) = 1 
          and r.result IS NOT NULL
         Then r.Result

         When r.DateType = 'M' 
          and Month(r.StartDate) = 1 
          and r.result IS NULL 
      and r.rating is NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(rtovr.ratingShortDesc,rt.ratingShortDesc)
    Else null
     END) as Value_January_1,

MAX(Case When r.DateType = 'M' 
          and Month(r.StartDate) = 1
         Then dbo.udfGetRating(case when r.RatingOverride is null            
                                    then r.Rating 
                               else r.RatingOverride 
                               end) + '|' + CAST(UserOverride AS CHAR(1)) + '|' + rt.ratingShortDesc
         Else null
     END) as Rating_January_1,


From #tblResults R

WHERE r.datetype IN ('M','Y')
```

... follows that case logic in the select all the way to Dec.

Example Data on table #tblResult:

```
EmployeeID Employee Datetype EmpGroupID PA EmpLevel ObjectiveName Objectiveid Weighting RPTYear ObjSortOrder ObjGrpSortOrder Result Rating RatingOverride startdate UserOverride 
552940 test Q 664 Sr Rep 1 Overall Rating -1 1 2012 0 0 2 2.00 NULL 2012-01-01 0
552940 test Q 664 Sr Rep 1 Overall Rating -1 1 2012 0 0 2.39 2.00 NULL 2012-04-01 0
```

Comment: That has to be the biggest single SQL statement EVER. ha.  I wouldn't suggest the pivot, you will have a problem with dates that have no data.  And yes, you can get around that but it is very ugly too.  Can you make this into a stored procedure?

Comment: hahaha, yes it is very long my frined. To answer your question yes, it current is a Sproc.  Currently its handling the NULLs by doing a check via a LEFT join on some config tables. [*posted full FROM statement below*]. You said you wouldn't recommend a pivot, what method would you recommend?

Comment: `code` From tblResults R INNER JOIN @Emphist h ON r.Empgroupid = h.Groupid LEFT OUTER JOIN Config.tblRatingDescription rt ON r.Rating = rt.RatingID LEFT OUTER JOIN Config.tblRatingDescription rtovr ON r.RatingOverride = rtovr.RatingID `code` @cha

Comment: The way you are doing it sucks.. but it is error proof (compared to pivot) and sometimes that is worth it.  I often write programs that are used to create code.  In your case, you have 365 cases, you would loop 365 times and produce code (in a varchar variable) for the repetitive code.